# I want to delete a constraint on a view in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I used to delete a constraint on  a view by clicking on the blue circle as shown in the image. But it is not working.

I think Android Studio team changed something in the UI of Android Studio?

**Details of my system**

O.S. -> Windows 10

Bit -> 64 bit

Android Studio -> 3.6.1

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5LBO.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

You can delete a constraint by doing any of the following:

- Click on a constraint to select it, and then press Delete.
- Press and hold Control (Command on macOS), and then click on a constraint anchor. Note that the constraint turns red to indicate that you can click to delete it
- In the Layout section of the Attributes window, click on a constraint anchor.

**Source**

[Add or remove a constraint](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#add-a-constraint)

Answer (score 2):

Just delete it in "Code" view, I think it's way easier to do things like this there. (Normally in the top-right corner you have three buttons when you have a layout file open: "Code", "Split", and "Design".)